# React testing-library Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing-library

I write a test for a seletion and I get this warning. In my test I'm waiting for the end of the act. Why I get this error?

> Warning: You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported. Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one.

```
test('Selection should be have the correct number of options', async () => {
  const leftClick = { button: 0 };
  const { options } = makeSUT();
  const selection = screen.getByLabelText('MultiSelection');

  // open all option
  act(() => {
    userEvent.click(selection, leftClick);
  });
  // await wait();

  options.forEach(async (option, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      expect((await screen.findAllByText(option.label)).length).toEqual(1);
    } else {
      expect((await screen.findAllByText(option.label)).length).toEqual(1);
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: The first item wrapped in `act` needs an `await`. RTL methods are wrapped in `act` so your assertion is using an `act` call before the first one has resolved.

Answer (score 11):

`userEvent` utility API methods should not be wrapped in `act()`. It is recommended not to do so [here](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/387#issuecomment-1021067064). Instead, you can just `await` the method call. After you have performed an action, you can use [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) to wait for the Component state to update and run your assertions. To simplify your logic, I would replace [findBy](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#findby-queries) with a `waitFor` and `getBy` so you're not having to `async` your `forEach()`.

You should ensure you are setting up `userEvent` correctly (see [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/setup))

The following should resolve your issue:

```js
test('Selection should be have the correct number of options', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup(); // Make sure to setup correctly.
    const leftClick = { button: 0 };
    const { options } = makeSUT();
    const selection = screen.getByLabelText('MultiSelection');
    
    // Wait for the userEvent to click:
    await user.click(selection, leftClick);
    waitFor(() => {
        options.forEach((option, index) => {
            if (index === 0) {
                expect((screen.getAllByText(option.label)).length).toEqual(1);
            } else {
                expect((screen.getAllByText(option.label)).length).toEqual(1);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Any idea why `await` works? Doesn't seem to be any mention of it in the docs.

Comment: I just checked out the docs I linked, and I can see that the example they use has `await user.click(element)`. They might not have done it in some other examples because perhaps they weren't using an async test.

Comment: @Matt I believe all RTL methods are wrapped in act. The waitFor is probably not necessary as you are waiting on that state update to complete before you are asserting.

Comment: @Davidicus I found inconsistencies in external testing CI pipelines when I did not use the `waitFor` before asserting when using RTL APIs like `type` or `keyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't wrap `userEvent.click` in `act`, you just need to `waitFor` the effect of the click to be visible.

I made a couple of small changes that leave us with a very readable test:

- Left clicking is the default, so we don't need to specify that.
- `getByText` returns the one element that matches the text, so you don't need to get all of the elements and check that there's only one.
- We're not using the `index` argument in `forEach` so we can drop that too.

```
test('Selection should be have the correct number of options', async () => {
  const { options } = makeSUT();

  const selection = screen.getByLabelText('MultiSelection');
  userEvent.click(selection);

  await waitFor(() => {
    options.forEach((option) => screen.getByText(option.label);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the warning when I use a `for of` loop. Try something like below

```
    let index = 0;
    for await (const option of options) {
      if (index === 0) {                
         expect((screen.getAllByText(option.label)).length).toEqual(1);
      } else {
         expect((screen.getAllByText(option.label)).length).toEqual(1);
      }
      index +=1;
    }
```